# All in one seo pack and qtranslate title attributes

Tags: wordpress, plugins, seo, title, translate

Does anyone now how can i use `[:en]text[:fr]other text` in the `Title Attribute:` option so when i am on the english version of site to show just the english text in the title attribute of the link and when i am on the french version to show only the french text, at this moment it shows both like this example:

[:en]text[:fr]other text

Comment: It works on Yoast SEO in 2019 though officially it's unsupported and QTranslate-X is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems with qTranslate and All-in-one SEO, because of the way they handle the title. I have not found a solution for this, but you can try to:

1. check out [this solution](http://www.matteoionescu.com/wordpress/qtranslatemeta/#squeezeform)
2. change one of the plugins - [WordPress SEO by Yoast](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/), [Polyglot](http://fredfred.net/skriker/index.php/polyglot/), [WPML](http://wpml.org/)